# Are there Unicode Letters which are neither upper- nor lower-case?

Tags: java, unicode

Are there Unicode-codepoints which represent letters but which are neither upper- nor lower-case?

In particular are there characters for which the Java-Function `java.lang.Character.isLetter` will return true, but `java.lang.Character.isUpperCase` and `java.lang.Character.isLowerCase` will return false?

Comment: I can't answer with regards to Java, but many Asian languages do not have a concept of "case", i.e. there's no upper or lower case variation of 漢字. Some have a concept of *letter width* though: カンジ, ｶﾝｼﾞ.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's trivial to test this for yourself:

```
public class Test {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    for (int i = Character.MIN_CODE_POINT;
         i <= Character.MAX_CODE_POINT;
         i++) {
      if (Character.isLetter(i) &&
          !Character.isUpperCase(i) &&
          !Character.isLowerCase(i)) {
        System.out.printf("%04x %c%n", i, i);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

You'll find that writes out lots of entries.

Comment: Is there any reason for the restriction to the Basic Multilingual Plane (BMP)? Since Java 1.5 all `Character.is*()` methods also support an `int` argument containing code points above the BMP.

Comment: +1: I would use `i <= Character.MAX_CODE_POINT` ;) and print the value of `i` as the character might not display.  To be pedantic, you could use `Character.MIN_CODE_POINT`

Comment: @A.H. Not particularly - fixing now.

Comment: @PeterLawrey: I was already printing out `i` instead of `c`, but yes - fixed the bounds now.

Comment: @JonSkeet My mistake. In that case I would include `(char) i` in case it is printable.

Comment: @PeterLawrey: Okay - and printing `i` in hex would probably be a good plan too... editing again :)+

Comment: @PeterLawrey: Better, use `i` in both cases, but format it with `%c`, which will cope with non-BMP characters too :)

Answer (score 3):

Not all scripts have the concept of upper and lower case letters, for example Thai. You should find that the Java API mirrors the Unicode data defined in the standard. For example, look at the Thai letter kho rakhang at http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/e06/index.htm

Answer (score 0):

Most of them. Chinese characters for instance. And if you check http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/text/charintro.html isLetter returns true, but they are neither lowercase or uppercase.